# ASP.NET MVC4 Get email of logged user

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, email, asp.net-mvc-4

I am making asp.net mvc4 web application. I wrote contact form function in my controller which sends feedback from users. I am using System.Net.Mail class.

I am using Simplemembership and I extended UserProfile with string Email property.

How to get logged in user Email? I want to include it it sended message, so I Could answer.

I tried to use:

```
var em = from m in db.UserProfiles.Where(a => a.UserName.Contains(User.Identity.Name)) select m.Email;
string email = em.ToString();
```

but in the sent mail I have:

```
SELECT
[Extent1].[Email] AS [Email]
FROM [dbo].[UserProfile] AS [Extent1]
WHERE [Extent1].[UserName] LIKE @p__linq__0 ESCAPE N'~'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To retrieve a single entry of the database, you have to select the first row returned with the `First()` method:

```
string email = db.UserProfiles
           .Where(a => a.UserName.Contains(User.Identity.Name))
           .First().Email;
```

Hope it helps !

Comment: In m.Email I got Error: Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'bool'. Am I miss something?

Comment: OK, I just change my string email = em.ToString(); to string email = em.First(); and it works. Thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 0):

You already have the correct answer, so I am just throwing this up here for future searchers to see the shorter syntax.

```
string email = db.UserProfiles
           .FirstOrDefault(a => a.UserName.Contains(User.Identity.Name)).Email;
```

However in your scenario, I would be concerned about `User1` receiving emails intended for `User11`. To prevent this, you need to be more specific in your query

```
string email = db.UserProfiles
           .FirstOrDefault(a => a.UserName == User.Identity.Name).Email;
```